# TSQL Как удалить все управляющие символы?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode

Как можно удалить все управляющие символы?

Для поиска таких записей использую следующий запрос:

```
select * from MyTable
where 
    TextField  LIKE '%[' + char(1)+ '-' + char(8) +']%'
    or TextField  LIKE '%[' +  char(10)+ '-' + char(31) +']%'
```

Можно конечно сделать REPLACE для каждого символа, но это не хорошо

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день, посмотрите в сторону следующих функций: [udf_PatExclude8K](https://github.com/ktaranov/sqlserver-kit/blob/master/User_Defined_Function/udf_PatExclude8K.sql) и [RemoveNonAlphaCharacters](https://github.com/ktaranov/sqlserver-kit/blob/master/User_Defined_Function/RemoveNonAlphaCharacters.sql)

Либо можно использовать [CLR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498(v=vs.130).aspx) (если позволяет политика безопасности организации) с полной поддержкой C# регулярных выражений: http://www.sqlsharp.com/